# If conditions in terraform map and objects to index based on key

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a strange situation as shown below

variable is declared as :

```
variable "subnet_info" {
type = map(object({vpc_name=string, subnet_name=string, subnet_ip_range=string, region=string}))
default = {
 abc = {
  vpc_name = "abc"
  subnet_name = "abc"
  subnet_ip_range = ""
  region = "europe-west3"
    }
 bcd = {
  vpc_name = "bcd"
  subnet_name = "bcd"
  subnet_ip_range = ""
  region = "europe-west3"
    }
  }
 }
```

I have declared a modules as follow

```
module "abc" {
  source = "./modular_approach/modules/general_network/"
  for_each = var.subnet_info
  individual_vpc_name = each.value
  individual_subnet_name = each.value
 }
```

I want to pass the value of vpc and subnet from the variable subnet_info. The problem is that there will be many values in that variable. If I run the for_each I want to condition in the module that if the key is "abc" then access the internal (key,value) other wise skip. Is this possible in terraform?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just pass the `abc` object into the module instead of all the unrelated networks?

Comment: did exactly the same. used lookup for that

Answer (score 1):

If you really wish to filter like that, the following construct should do :

```
for_each = {for k,v in var.subnet_info: k=>v if k == "abc"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Marcin. I how ever did with the lookup(lookup())

Comment: @dumb_coder Thanks for letting me know. And yes, somehow I forgout about lookup. Anyway, glad it worked out either way :-)